# XCode not linking on dependency (.a) change unless executable is deleted

Tags: xcode, linker

I have a sub-sub-project (a child of a child of the top level project) in XCode that produces a static library that the top level project links against. The output of the sub-sub-project is in the Build Settings > Link Binary With Libraries list (though not in the Target Dependencies, because XCode will only let you put immediate children in there). If I delete the Executable Unix File in the AppPackage in the Build directory, it does build correctly. It's just not recognizing that the library being changed should cause the executable to link, even though it worked fine this morning. I've checked git and the project files are unchanged. What could be going on? (I'm gonna reboot as soon as I post this)

Edit: Rebooting didn't work. Going to a previous commit didn't work. I'm beginning to wonder if it never worked right.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Only way to get the app to link to the new version of the static lib is to clean before building. And I even have the static lib project set as a dependency.